# Android - How to get a user's object ID from Parse and store it in a string

Tags: android, parse-platform

I am making a test Sign UP activity for an app that I am planning, and I want to get the user that signed up 's object  after the user signs up successfully.
Here's some of my code:

```
public void signUp(View v){
String firstNameString = FirstName.getText().toString();
String familyNameString = LastName.getText().toString();
String emailString = email.getText().toString();

if (firstNameString.length()<2){
    Context context = getApplicationContext();
    CharSequence text = "Your first name must be at least 2 characters";
    int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;

    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, text, duration);
    toast.show();
}

if (familyNameString.length()<2){
    Context context = getApplicationContext();
    CharSequence text = "Your family name must be at least 2 characters";
    int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;

    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, text, duration);
    toast.show();
}
if (firstNameString.isEmpty()){
    Context context = getApplicationContext();
    CharSequence text = "Please Enter a First Name";
    int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;

    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, text, duration);
    toast.show();
}
if (familyNameString.isEmpty()){
    Context context = getApplicationContext();
    CharSequence text = "Please Enter a First Name";
    int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;

    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, text, duration);
    toast.show();
}
else {
    ParseUser user = new ParseUser();
    user.setUsername(firstNameString + familyNameString);
    user.setEmail(emailString);
    user.setPassword("null");

user.signUpInBackground(new SignUpCallback() {
    public void done(ParseException e) {
        if (e == null) {
        Context context = getApplicationContext();
            CharSequence success = "Sign up Successfull";
            int duration = Toast.LENGTH_LONG;

            Toast successfullTostConformation = Toast.makeText(context,success,duration);
            successfullTostConformation.show();
        }
        else {
            // Sign up didn't succeed. Look at the ParseException
            // to figure out what went wrong
            Context context = getApplicationContext();
            CharSequence success = "Sign up failed. Check your internet connection";
            int duration = Toast.LENGTH_LONG;

            Toast successfullTostConformation = Toast.makeText(context,success,duration);
            successfullTostConformation.show();
        }
    }
});
        }



}
```

That's my onclick listener for the sign up button. So, as I said, how do I get the user's Object ID, store it in a string, and then save it locally.
I've tried for the first step:

```
String userID = user.getObjectID
```

However I have an error under `user.getObjectID();`
**Variable 'user' is accessed from within inner class, needs to be declared final**

**Edit:** Oh. I had to put `String userID = user.getObjectID` under `ParseUser user = new ParseUser();`.
Thanks to anyone who tried to help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh. I had to put `String userID = user.getObjectID` under `ParseUser user = new ParseUser();`.
Thanks to anyone who tried to help